# layering absolute positioned div on top of table cells

Tags: html, css

Given the following html code, how can I make the z-index red div overlap all the cells. The catch is that the red div must be positioned absolute so that it does not affect the cell contents.

```html
<html>
 <table style="position:relative;z-index:0;">
  <tr style="height:100px;position:relative;z-index:0;">
   <td style="position:relative;width:200px;height:inherit;background-color:green;border:solid 2px green;z-index:0;overflow:visible;">
       <div style="position:absolute;background-color:red;height:inherit;width:100%;top:10px;left:10px;z-index:500;"></div>
       xyz
   </td>
   <td style="position:relative;width:200px;height:inherit;background-color:green;border:solid 2px green;z-index:0"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr style="height:100px;position:relative;z-index:0">
   <td style="position:relative;width:200px;height:inherit;background-color:green;border:solid 2px green;z-index:0"></td>
   <td style="position:relative;width:200px;height:inherit;background-color:green;border:solid 2px green;z-index:0"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `z-index` from all the elements and give `z-index: 1` to the red `div`'s parent element(`td`).

```html
<html>
<table style="position:relative;">
  <tr style="height:100px;position:relative;">
    <td style="position:relative;width:200px;height:inherit;background-color:green;border:solid 2px green;z-index:1;overflow:visible; ">
      <div style="position:absolute;background-color:red;height:inherit;width:100%;top:10px;left:10px;"></div>
      xyz
    </td>
    <td style="position:relative;width:200px;height:inherit;background-color:green;border:solid 2px green;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height:100px;position:relative;">
    <td style="position:relative;width:200px;height:inherit;background-color:green;border:solid 2px green;"></td>
    <td style="position:relative;width:200px;height:inherit;background-color:green;border:solid 2px green;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</html>
```

Comment: Actually I found removing all z-indexes all together, and then just applying a zindex on the div worked.

Comment: And the reason why thats better - is because we need to assume the red div layer could be in multiple td elements. Thanks for the feedback. Why does the z-index only work if the cell does not contain a z-index?